# asp.net - Select2 change Dropdownlist item colour if contains a string

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, jquery-select2

I have this Select 2 DropDownList:

```
      $(document).ready(function () {            

      $("#<%=ddl_modelo_equipamento.ClientID%>").select2({

          placeholder: "Selecione um Modelo"

      });

  });
```

And I have this Code Behind which is called based on another DropDownList Changed Value that loads the information on this select2 DropDownList:

```
 private void changeColor(DropDownList ddl_modelo_equipamento)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in ddl_modelo_equipamento.Items)
            {
                string descricao = item.Text;

                if (descricao.Contains("; Stock: 0 unid."))
                {

                    item.Attributes.Add("style", "color:red");
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
```

For each item in the DropDownList that contains this string `"; Stock: 0 unid."` I want the font colour to be changed to red and it isn't changing with a Select2 DropDownList but if I change it to a normal asp DropDownList it changes the colour.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Because a `<asp:DropDownList />` renders out a standard `<select>` with `<option>`'s, and select2 replaces that markup with `<div>`, `<span>` and `<ul>`'s. Probably when you add that attribute it gets added to the hidden `<option>` but the corresponding select2 element is un-affected.

Comment: What code can I use to change the color of the item in Select2

Comment: Well, for starters it would probably be better to handle this in javascript and not your code-behind. Add a `change` event handler to select2 and do your update there.

Comment: The thing is that I am really clueless about how to make this, fr